# Local fullwidth environment in symmetric document with margin

Tags: margins, double-sided, marginpar

In a symmetric twoside document with 5cm margin on the outer side of each page, I want to create an enviroment where I can place locally a piece of text of full page width. Any solution that I have tried so far does not create the desired effect. For example the custom `narrow` environment shown in the MWE adds margin on the current page, but when the text goes to the next page, it vanishes at the edge.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,symmetric]{book}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0,BoldFont={Times New Roman Bold}]{Times New Roman}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inner=2.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=12cm,marginparsep=5mm,marginparwidth=5cm}

\newenvironment{narrow}[2]{%
   \begin{list}{}{%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
   \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}}%
\item[]}{\end{list}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum\lipsum
\begin{narrow}{0cm}{-5cm}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{narrow}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to adjust the textwidth no matter if the page is even or odd?

Comment: The `changepage` package defines an `adjustwidth` environment.

Comment: I used `adjustwidth ` but the problem with the next page remains. It's because it changes the left and right margins. I want to be able to change locally the inner and outer margins of the even and odd pages.

Comment: I didn't understand what a *symmetric* document means. You do want a piece of text which  extends on the full paper width, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes that's right. Without getting the result as shown in the pictures.

Comment: You didn't explain what ‘symmetric’ docume nt means.

Comment: It is an option for the book class. I do not know exactly what it means and how it affects the document. I think it places the sidenotes on the outside of the page.

Comment: Actually LaTeX warns you about that: `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [symmetric].`

Comment: if your document had equal left and right margins, then you could use your `narrow` environment and specify the same negative value to both argument. As you have it with a wide outer margin, it's much harder to do.

Comment: are you using luatex or xetex? (a luatex-only solution might be easier)

Comment: I am using XeLatex. I managed to create a narrower environment but it works on each page separately, not when the text goes to the next page.